# how to increase listview height as the user is scrolling down

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to make a list view witch will grow to be fuLLscreen (height) as the user is scrolling down, if the user scrolled lets say 30dp, the whole list's height will be increased by 30 dp, how should I do this?

Comment: Have you considered adding your other components as header of the list and making the list fullscreen all the time?

Comment: good idea, I want the part above the listview to scroll slower then the list itself, something like the Google Play Music app, do you know how to do this?

Comment: I don't use google play... but I have an idea of what you're talking about. Never did something in that area. Maybe you can create an own view (probably a `ListView` subclass) that influences scrolling or something like that.